# Proof that e is transcendental in Herstein's Topics in Algebra (1st ed)

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, polynomials, transcendental-numbers

In the proof of Theorem 5.F. page 177.

[page 176](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7PBV.png)
[page 177](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7DWk.png)
From the constructed $F(x)$ from $f(x),$ how can we choose $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(p-1)!}x^{p-1}(1-x)^{p}(2-x)^{p}\cdots(n-x)^{p}$$ where $p>n$ and $p>c_{0}.$

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to Herstein's book, this was the first proof of transcendence of $e$ for me when there was no wiki and Google had just arrived. Also it was a welcome surprise to find highly analytical proof in textbook of algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused as to what depends on what. In the construction described in the two linked pages, Herstein shows how to construct a polynomial $F$ from any polynomial $f$. He then specifies that he will choose $f$ to be
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{(p-1)!}x^{p-1}(1-x)^{p}(2-x)^{p}\cdots(n-x)^{p},$$
for some large prime $p$ larger than $n$ and $c_0$. As there are infinitely many primes, there exists some prime $p$ larger than both $n$ and $c_0$, and thus it is possible to construct that $f$ --- and from that $f$, it is possible to construct $F$.

Comment: Thanks, my question is what is the motivation behind of selecting such a form for $f(x)$? If I don't see the proof, I do not know how to arrive at such form.

Comment: They key about this polynomial is that it and all of its first very many derivatives at each integer up to $n$ are all $0$.